# Why does fireshepard kill firesheep?

Tags: security, exploit

I presume there is a bug in the `firesheep` which `fireshepard` exploits.
The responsible line might be in that weird string in cookie value for facebook.

[fireshepard source](http://notendur.hi.is/~gas15/FireShepherd/FireShepherd.cpp)
[firesheep source](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran both FireShepard and FireSheep, that "weird string" causes a syntax error while parsing the JSON result for the mock Facebook cookie because the input is not properly escaped.

see [Issue 88](https://github.com/codebutler/firesheep/issues/issue/88)

It looks like the specific place it is failing is in FiresheepWorker.js in this portion of the code:

```
/* Read stdout until process exits */
      var line;
      while (line = process.ReadOutputLine()) {
        var packet = JSON.parse(line);
        this._processPacket(packet);
      }

      /* Read any errors */
      var errors = [];
      while (line = process.ReadErrorLine()) {
        errors.push(line);
      }
```

Here is the Cookie value from Fireshepard source for reference :

> "Cookie: lsd=spsse; c_user=666660000;
>   sct=01010101; sid=0;
>   xs=3randomhashyes666666666;
>   asdf=??????????????!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!%•eëÒˆY¼¥­Áøþh¡F4£A€
>   º¦SÍÂÝåt¹Òv5þhèŸË&%%¥Ô$FsnÄ‹xÏÏvVfi6ƒÊìÈ_7Î½çÜQlXËFÿë~~½¹ùÉÛ,÷7¬ùüyóÇ>hº_ošŸ¿ÄGÜ5¼yy{ÃZÆ|øË,þÊjo¬´­W¢y¹¹y5ù|Êmk¤P“Ãt¦[%´Ô“û)7­°f²›ÎDk¹0vò€_ykW“ÛÝ=þ‹ËV©&«þ×åtfç­ðÔS{/Z9Yàé½n­lãï¬ÅÇÛåô/u#8“´Ã—¯±šÿìÇúyøëO^ˆn73®¥“ÐŠ·LÄÏ1MKºGGÖ:
>   Íìd3MCÌ§iñ_õ{[Ïs§‡0gÂë´
>   ž»°n~)ºù…áF7ÂKÙzG_O~9}ùöÆ1XÓ™4ÀwSA»Ó<Ø®ûu…ß“™×SÕ2ãŸ,¦®åÒ11ÙçN‡Ý|—×ÿI·Íâœa˜ŠÃÞgtçÓ´Áeþm?å¢0Éb:K“RÛv:KÓ¯º£øìåÍïoð¡nþtÃ-Ó€@có­tÍ¦o±Íúæó³L+>…
>   5-    ÃÒX&bð³lˆ[ $¯DZJ\r\n\r\n";
>       request+="\r\n";